# How can I fill this gap between the plasterboard and window architrave?

Tags: drywall, windows

The framing on my house is warped in such a way that I have several places where I have large gaps between the window/door architraves and the frame and the plasterboard just flaps around. I also get the feeling that whoever hung the plasterboard thought that screws were really expensive.

[image: Window]

This one window already has a some gap filler in it, but the gap has widened.
Two options I can think of are to insert wedges to push the plaster back then use more gap filler, or pull the plasterboard forward and glue it to the back of the window frame.

Or is there a better idea I can't think of?

Comment: If the gap is growing then you need to look into the underlying cause of that problem. Any patch you do now will be a waste of time if the walls/window continue to move.

Answer (score 3):

I am having a bit of a problem understanding why plaster board or sheetrock would be finished to door and window jams without a casing/molding frame. In the few instances I have seen flush fitting walls to doors/windows, the wall covering is a thin, finished edge panel of some type, not 1/2" rock. In your case, the pic looks like the edge of the was was simply finished with some type of caulk or sealant to the jam, and either the jams have cupped or the caulking has shrunk over time causing the gaps to appear.

My first option would be to case the doors and windows with a molding. This would cover the gaps and secure the "flapping" wall board.  The second option could be to use an elastomer paintable caulk/sealant to fill the gaps. I might use some finish nails to tighten the wall board and counter sink the nails slightly and fill and finish the holes. Hint: cover the jams and edge of the wall board with blue painter's tape before applying the caulk. Smooth the caulk into the gaps with a putty knife, then immediately remove the tape, leaving a nice crisp, straight line.

Comment: It's a common 'style' in cheaper homes and/or, for some reason, in the Pacific Northwest of the US (I see TONS of homes out here where windows are all finished with sheetrock corners...no trim). I suppose it's a bit of a more 'contemporary' look, though my gut says it's just cheaper to build.